# Space gap on top of Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4

how can I let the Chromium to fill the gap on top of the screen?

I have set the autostart like this already:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank

@chromium-browser --app --start-fullscreen  <URL>
```

but still appear like below image

[image: rapsberry pi with top gap]